# mysql replace piece of a string for some entries

Tags: mysql

I have a table "mytable" with a field "name" of varchar. I need to replace the string "iphone" in each string to "blackberry" how can I do that in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE mytable
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'iphone', 'blackberry')
```

Comment: great thanks!! I added WHERE LIKE "%iphone%" at the end to try to make it faster UPDATE mytable
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'iphone', 'blackberry') WHERE LIKE "%iphone%"